# Data v/s Index paths for Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

Slide #11 of http://www.slideshare.net/Couchbase/sizing-couchbase-server-cbc2014-clean suggests using different data paths for data and indexes. What does that mean exactly ?

I see the following under the default data folder ( /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/data )

1 folder per bucket
1 folder called @indexes
some other files.
The bucket data and index data appears to be in separate paths already. Should they be on separate disks instead ?

Also, As per http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Misc/admin-datafiles.html , 
"The default disk path is typically used for development purposes only. If the server node is used for production, configure a different disk path." . If the couchbase server node has just 1 disk and is mounted on "/", does it make sense to change the "default" paths ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two different volumes (whether physical or cloud block storage) then it certainly makes sense to split the data and index paths to those separate volumes to improve performance and reduce disk IO contention between the different workloads (data vs. indexes). If you just have one volume, there are no performance gains to be had, but it might be more convenient to have the data folder separate from the Couchbase installation location.